# Image Alternate Text is Not Working

Tags: html, google-chrome

I'm sure I'm going to smack myself when someone points out what I'm doing wrong, but I cannot for the life of me figure out why I can't get an alternate text to appear when an image does not load.

I have the following code with obviously the wrong path to an image (to simulate the image not loading for some reason):

```
<form>
    <input type="image" src="image/not.here" alt="Search"/>
</form>
```

However, I don't get a button with the text "Search" on it which is what I would expect.

Can I accomplish this?

Thanks!

jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/kralco626/hd4Dy/4/

Comment: Why you use value"Find" instead value="Find"?

Comment: @PiLHA - typo, the value isn't even relivant, updating the question and fiddle, thanks

Answer (score 3):

If you're using Google Chrome/Safari, the browser don't display the "Search" if it is longer than the img width.
There's nothing wrong with your code. Try add `style="width: 700px; height: 400px"` on your second input tag just to see that the text is there.

Further information:

http://blog.paciellogroup.com/2010/01/alt-and-title-content-display-in-popular-browsers/

PS: I.E. is showing the "Search" text.

Comment: This is it. You can also use `<img src="x" height="100" width="25">`

Comment: Mas olha só, um pessoense por essas bandas :)

Comment: OK, ya, i see it's just a chrome issue. I'll add the tag "Chrome" to the question to make it useful for others. I really hate to have to specify a width, just to make the alt text work :/

Comment: @PiLHA olha só! Pois é, tem poucos por aqui hahah

Answer (score 1):

You're missing a `=`:

```
value="Find"
```

Also, it depends on the browser. Some show the [`alt`](http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/input.image.html#input.image.attrs.alt) text in case the image is not available others don't; so it's not an *error* per se. Browsers for the visual impaired, for example, always show it.