# why alt in html not display the text?

Tags: html

I know alt attribute is used to display text if only image cannot be displayed. 
I disable viewing images in google chrome and try the below code but the text is not displayed. why?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>Hello</head>
<body>
<img src="raja.jpg" alt="This is image text" title="This is tool tip">
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You sure alt is triggered in this instance? the asset is there so it is not technically a broken link

Comment: I think it blocks the entire `<img>` tag, not just the download of the image.

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18087447/image-alternate-text-is-not-working

Comment: then alt attribute display the text if the link is broken ?

Comment: That's not exactly a duplicate; adding width/etc. allows it to show up when broken link, but not when it images are turned off

Comment: thanks joe now i am clear

Comment: http://rebuildingtheweb.com/en/how-should-browsers-render-alt-text/ makes me more clear

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's seems a bug of Webkit (engine of browser), he doesn't render the attribute alt, how to show this bugs traces.

[Chromium](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=773)

[WebKit Bugzilla](https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=5566)

Comment: yes it's bug http://rebuildingtheweb.com/en/how-should-browsers-render-alt-text/ makes me more clear